# Missing debug file is slowing down my application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I've created a solution with a portable class library and a windows phone project. In the PCL i do some HttpClient action but I experience that my app is so slow.

So I went in and did a Debug(timestap) all over the place, narrowing it down to where I did get HttpClient request magic, :-). I then noticed the following line

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\..\System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

What is this? Can I skip it? My request to my server takes forever (10-20 sec) and if its using this time to look for the PDB file that does not exits I totally get it. I changed my solution to use RELEASE settings but i get that same output from my debugger.

How can I fix that?

Comment: The PDB are loaded by the debugger. It won't happen when you launch the app without the debugger.

Comment: @KooKiz Well, if I run the application on the phone without connecting it to the computer for debugging it is still so slow. 99% sure its the HttpClient in the PCL

Comment: It may be the HttpClient, but if it occurs without the debugger then it's not related the PDB